# Trouble with implementing contextual links

Tags: 7

I have a block with dynamic content and two contextual links.

I have at the moment two problems:

1. The second element is not visible.
2. The first link does not allow to pass a date. I have to set a prefix e.g. "_"

How can I fix this problems?

Here is the main part of my module:

```
define('MY_DIR', 'somedir');

function mymodule_menu() {
    $items[MY_DIR] = array(
        'page callback' => 'status_page',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
$items[MY_DIR.'/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'status_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
);
    $items[MY_DIR.'/edit'] = array(
        'title' => 'Edit item',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('mymodule_object_edit_form', 2),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    );
    $items[MY_DIR.'/%date/update'] = array(
        'title' => 'Edit date',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('mymodule_object_edit_form', 2),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

And here is my status page:

```
function status_page($date=null) {
    $object=new stdClass();
    $build=array();

    if(empty($date)) {
        $day=get_next_match();
    } else {
        // parse data
    }

    // set title
    $title="Title for ".$day->format("j.m.Y");
    drupal_set_title($title);

    $object->title = $title;
    $object->content = "Some dynamic content";

    $build[0] = array(
        '#theme' => 'filteredusers_object',
        '#object' => $object,
        '#contextual_links' => array(
            // contextual link 1
            'update-option' => array(
                MY_DIR,
                array("_$date"),
            ),
            // contextual link 2
            'edit.option' => array(
                MY_DIR.'/edit',
                array(),
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $build;
}
```

If something is unclear feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day of research I got a solution:

```
$build[1] = array(
    '#theme' => 'filteredusers_object',
    '#object' => $object,
    '#contextual_links' => array(array('', array())), // replaced by dummy data
    '#marker' => 'marker',
);
```

And adding this new hook:

```
function filteredusers_contextual_links_view_alter(&$element, &$items) {
    if(isset($element['#element']['#marker']) && 
             $element['#element']['#marker'] == "marker") {
        $element['#links']['custom-link'] = array(
            'title' => 'Some title',
            'href' => url('node/42', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
        );
    }
}
```